# Finding 2 variables that differs the most and combining them into one variable

Tags: r, dataframe, variables, difference

I am predicting bankruptcy for 17 successful companies. For each of the companies (1 - 17):

- I have calculated the values of 6 bankruptcy predicting models (A, L, T, S, Z, CH);
- And marked: "1" - bankruptcy is likely (red), "0" - bankruptcy is unpredictable (gray), "-1" - bankruptcy is unlikely (green).

[image: Example (data for the first 4 companies)]

All the cells in the first block have to be green, because the companies are successful. However, I get different values and colors. And my task is to find out, that 2 models (of these 6) can be applied together to get the biggest amount of green cells for each company.

My solution:

Let's say, we compare the pair of A and L models:

- First row: If we have two green cells, as the result we get green cell. Ok.
- Second row: green and red. We cannot get green here.
- Third row: green.
- Fourth row: red.

If I need to repeat it for all pairs of models and in this way find that two of them makes the most green cells?

Comment: Please include sample data (not as [image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)) and desired result. See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5965451). Consider also showing us the conditional format logic that colors the cells.